# Automate interaction with an Android application inside a Docker container

Tags: android, docker, automation, appium

I am trying to build a bot to automate interactions with a mobile app, an example use case would be to automatically like whatever my friend posts on Instagram. I would like to be able to deploy to a cloud compute provider with Docker.

What software would be best for this? I've looked into Appium, but it seems that's more focused on testing.

Thanks